# Can't start Angular application

Tags: angular, npm, single-page-application

Within the last few days, we have been encountering the following errors (and there doesn't seem to be match find in Google search):

```
npm start

ng serve

Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Error: Error on worker #1: TypeError: compiler_1.createMayBeForwardRefExpression is not a function
```

Any ideas why or workaround?

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by the version mismatch for most Angular framework packages(like core, common, compiler) with @angular/compiler-cli and @angular/language-service.

You should always use the same versions of these packages. Try using "^" with the version number.

Answer (score 1):

As @a_tk explained, that is the usual issue here.

You need edit your package.json file and search for those packages (*angular*) and use the caret(^) instead of tilde(~) before the package version, example:

From this:

`"@angular/cli": "~12.0.1",`

To this:

```
"@angular/cli": "^12.2.0",
```

Then, to avoid related issues, I recommend delete **node_modules** directory and **package-lock.json** file and run:

```
npm i
```

I hope this help others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your global typscript  package

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

Comment: tried that command "npm install -g typescript@latest" - but same error

Comment: Try to remove your node module folder and run npm install again after removing package.lock file

Comment: tried that also without success

Answer (score 0):

Changing the package.json dependency as below resolved the issue for me

"@angular/compiler": "12.2.13", to "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.13",

Answer (score 0):

Both answers from @a_tk and @manuelpgs could/should resolve the issue but most **important** is :

- If you delete **node_modules** folder make sure you delete **package-lock.json** as well because if you dont you might spend hours on debugging versions (like silly me) and will not help you as long as locked file is present your versions might mismatch.

Using `ng update` you might shorten process to see what needs to update to  what version. There might be additional packages which don't provide 'ng update' capabilities that are outdated but it might help solving issue.